# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int' , while extracting the table contents from pdf

Tags: python-3.x

I want to extract the table and contents from pdf file and show in the list of strings based on new line, but while splinting the row, type error is showing. where I am making mistake?

```
import numpy
import PyPDF2

fd = open('./sample2.pdf', 'rb')
pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fd)
page = pdfreader.getPage(1)
content = page.extractText()
tableList = content.split('\n')
#table has four columns
lines = numpy.array_split(tableList, len(tableList/4))
# displaying row by row 
for i in range(0,5):
    print(lines[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dividing the list `tableList` by `4`, replace this line:

```
lines = numpy.array_split(tableList, len(tableList/4))
```

By this:

```
lines = numpy.array_split(tableList, len(tableList)/4)
```

Comment: Thank you MrGreek, I could able to resolve the issue

Comment: This will give you a float instead of an int

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh numpy will convert it to an int.